# call a xml or json web services using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, cordova

I am trying to call a xml or json web services using jquery ajax for my phonegap application can any one help me out, I am getting (Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.) and then parser error.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
        var curcode = "AFA";
        var serviceURL =
            "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            contentType: "application/x-javascript",
            url: "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries'
            },
            // data: requestData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("good");
                var response = msg.d;
                console.log(msg);
                alert("response.Message : " +
                    response.Message);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("bad");
                console.log(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

When I run , I got below error :

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.*

Any solutions? Thanks in Advance.

can any one help me

Comment: Try a search; has been answered many times

Comment: thanks for your valuable advice but i could not find proper kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making cross domain request.
Hence you must retrieve data with JSONP type format. Not with JSON.

Hence Try by changing

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```